# Alignment problems in the Extension Library Application Layout Placebar in IE but not Firefox

Tags: css, xpages

Got an interesting CSS problem. The first graphic shows the buttons on the PlaceBar in IE where the "Views" button is pushed up. This button has children if this makes a difference. In FireFox everything lines up perfectly. Does anyone know if this is adjustable in the CSS and if so where?

[image: Bad alignment using IE8/7]

[image: Good alignment using FF]

Comment: Roy, can you add the placeBar part of your code with the buttons? I'll see if I can reproduce and fix it (tomorrow).

Comment: Also details on the version of IE would be helpful for reproducing it.

Comment: It turns out to be a Compatibility Mode issue in IE8. Turn it off and it lines up. Of course that could cause other issues down the road.

Comment: Interesting, on some pages the tabs line up perfectly yet on other pages, those with forms, those tabs with children are offset. Not sure why one page would line up and another wouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force IE not to use compatibility mode by using the X-UA-Compatible meta tag to control the version of IE to render the page for.

Add the following meta tag to enable IE8 Standards Mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" >
```

You can add the meta tag in a theme using:

```
<resources>
  <metaData>
    <httpEquiv>X-UA-Compatible</httpEquiv>
    <content>IE=8</content>
  </metaData>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 3):

I've found another fix. Add this to the CSS:

```
.lotusPlaceBar .lotusBtnContainer {
    float: right;
}
```