# XPages DojoDataGrid does not show data in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: xpages, dojox.grid.datagrid

I use DojoDatagrid to show data with scrollable. I check restServices works great but in previev with IE11 nothing happens. there is [image: Rest Service Screenshot here]only empty screen. 
([image: Rest Service screenshot]

I have searched then i found it's IE11 compatibility problem. I tried everything i could but I couldn't be succeeded. 
This kind of codes do not work for me :( 
http://www.bizzybee.be/2014/03/05/internet-explorer-pain-how-to-bypass-forced-compatibility-mode-on-your-intranet/

`response.setHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=10")`

Comment: What version of domino are you using, and any fix packs installed?

Comment: as far as i know No fix is installed and the version of Domino is IBM Domino Server (Release 9.0.1 for Windows/32)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE11 support was only added to Dojo in version 1.9.2: https://dojotoolkit.org/blog/dojo-1-9-2-and-more

Domino 9.0.1 contains Dojo 1.8.3, however the dojo version has been upgraded several times in 9.0.1 fix packs.

- Fix pack 2: Dojo 1.9.2
- Fix pack 3: Dojo 1.9.4
- Fix pack 4: Dojo 1.9.7

Fix pack 5 is the most recent fix pack, containing the same dojo version as fix pack 4. You would need to upgrade to one of those fix packs in order to pick up the new dojo and IE11 support.

Comment: as fas as i understand when i change application theme to bootstrap 3.2.0 dataGrid does not display data. If i changed them to OneUI or Default data will be shown on DojoDataGrid. 
have you got an idea why it's happeing with bootstrap theme?

Comment: I will upgrade that server then i will check it out. I hope FP4 or FP5 help me to fix this ...